# sqlCopyTable command in RODBC

Tags: r, postgresql, rodbc

I am trying to copy a simple data frame to a SQL table on my local server using the RODBC library. I want to use copy as opposed to writeTable because eventually I will be attempting to do this with extremely large sets of data and I need this to be done with speed.

I have already created the table in PostgreSQL 9.4. It is called "Example" and has two columns, one of character input and one of numeric input.

I read in a csv called "df", which has two columns of class character and numeric.

Then my code is as follows:

```
cd<- odbcConnect("public")

sqlClear(channel = cd, sqtable = 'public.example', errors = TRUE)

sqlCopyTable(channel = cd, srctable = df, desttable = "example", destchannel = cd, errors = TRUE)
```

The connection and the clear command both work with no problems. When I run the copy command, I get the following error which seems to just list the first column in my data frame:

```
Error in odbcTableExists(channel, stablename, abort = errors) : 
  ‘c("RCP Average", "NBC/WSJ", "FOX News", "Bloomberg", "Quinnipiac", "CNN/ORC", "CBS/NYT", "ABC/Wash Post", "CNN/ORC", "Monmouth", "PPP (D)", "Quinnipiac", "CNN/ORC", "FOX News", "Rasmussen", "FOX News", "Monmouth", "Bloomberg", "CBS News", "NBC/WSJ", "Quinnipiac", "Rasmussen", "CNN/ORC", "PPP (D)", "ABC/Wash Post", "FOX News", "USAT/Suffolk", "Monmouth", "CNN/ORC", "FOX News", "NBC/WSJ", "Monmouth", "FOX News", "CNN/ORC", "ABC/Wash Post", "Quinnipiac", "FOX News", "PPP (D)", "NBC/WSJ", "FOX News", 
"Quinnipiac", "CNN/ORC", "FOX News", "PPP (D)", "ABC/Wash Post", "CNN/ORC", "McClatchy/Marist", "Quinnipiac", "PPP (D)", "CNN/ORC", "FOX News", "CNN/ORC", "ABC/Wash Post", "McClatchy/Marist", "CNN/ORC", "Quinnipiac", "Rasmussen", "ABC/Wash Post", "McClatchy/Marist", "McClatchy/Marist", "FOX News", "CNN/ORC", "Quinnipiac", "CNN/ORC", "CNN/ORC", "ABC/Wash Post", "FOX News", "McClatchy/Marist", "Reason-Rupe", "WPA (R)", "CNN/ORC", "PPP (D)", "McClatchy/Marist", "CNN/ORC", "PPP (D)", "
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here and how I can make this copy command work? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any chance that there was more text in that error message that got lost while copy+pasting it into your question?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I ran it over and over again just to make sure. This was it for the error message. @joran